# Why do I get weird integers when looping through an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, integer

Here's my C++ code, meant to loop through and print out structs' properties at the end.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
   int red;
   int green;
   int blue;
} card_t;

int main()
{
   int colorPalette[][3] =
   {
      { 168,   0,  32 },
      { 228,  92,  16 },
      { 248, 216, 120 },
      {  88, 216,  84 },
      {   0, 120, 248 },
      { 104,  68, 252 },
      { 216,   0, 204 },
      { 248, 120, 248 }
   };
   int colorCount = (sizeof(colorPalette) / sizeof(*colorPalette));

   int    deckSize = colorCount * 2;
   card_t deck[deckSize];

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      for (int x = 0; x < colorCount; x++)
      {
         int    red   = colorPalette[x][0];
         int    green = colorPalette[x][1];
         int    blue  = colorPalette[x][2];
         card_t card  = { red, green, blue };
         deck[i + 1] = card;

         std::cout << card.red << ' ' << card.green << ' ' << card.blue <<
            std::endl;
         std::cout << "======" << std::endl;
      }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < deckSize; i++)
   {
      std::cout << deck[i].red << ' ' << deck[i].green << ' ' << deck[i].blue
                << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

When I `cout` the values in the first loop block, they turn out fine, but in the final one, I get:

```
-1665734512 32653 -1651136112
248 120 248
248 120 248
0 -1653342144 32653
-1653436608 32653 -1656110705
32653 -1653337504 32653
1116561856 32767 -1653337504
32653 6 0
6 16 6296320
0 0 0
1116562424 32767 1116562408
32767 1 0
1116562096 32767 -1653270346
32653 1 32653
0 0 -1653444720
32653 -1665734512 32653
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Why do you keep overwriting `deck[i+1]` each time through the inner loop? When it's done, it will always contain the values from `colorPalette[colorCount-1]`, so what's the purpose of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be due to wrong iteration over the `deck` array:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int x=0; x<colorCount; x++){
        int red=        colorPalette[x][0];
        int green=      colorPalette[x][1];
        int blue=       colorPalette[x][2];
        card_t card=    {red, green, blue};
        deck[i*colorCount + x]=      card;
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

What you seem to intend to do is to represent a two-dim array using one-dim array, which can be done like shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `deck` is to be filled with `colorPalette[]` twice over, hence `deckSize = colorCount*2;`.

In the first loop, where you are filling in the values in `deck`, you are printing to screen from the local `card` variable, not from the values stored in deck. See `std::cout<<card.red<< (...)`, you are using the local variable.

As for why the values on the second loop are wrong, it's because you are storing them wrong; the indexes are wrong. You want to iterate `deck` in the range [0, deckSize-1], but `i+1` will be 1 and 2, on the first and second outer loop, respectively. So, you keep overwriting on deck[1], and deck[2]. That is why the second and third values printed are "248 120 248", the last value to be written. The other numbers are simply random, uninitialized memory space.

`deck[(i*colorCount) + x]= card;` works as I think you intended.

Also, this looks more like C code than C++. You could use std::vector, iterators and C++ struct.